# How to create a blank row under specific cells?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to create a formula to read and transform the range bellow creating a blank row every time the date changes.
This would be the end goal:

| Date | Letter |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 06/12 | b |  |  |  |
| 06/12 | c |  |  |  |
| 06/12 | d |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 06/13 | e |  |  |  |
| 06/13 | f |  |  |  |
| 06/13 | g |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 06/14 | h |  |  |  |
| 06/14 | i |  |  |  |
| 06/14 | j |  |  |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following formula-

```
=REDUCE(A1:B1,A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A)),
    LAMBDA(a,x,
        VSTACK(a,
            IF(x=INDEX(A:A,ROW(x)+1),
                INDEX(A:B,ROW(x)),
                VSTACK(INDEX(A:B,ROW(x)),HSTACK(" "," "))
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the dates in the range A2:A, you can use:

```
=REDUCE(TOCOL(,1),A2:A,LAMBDA(a,c,{a;IF(c=OFFSET(c,1,),c,{c;""})}))
```

#### Update

```
=REDUCE(TOCOL(,1),SEQUENCE(COUNT(A2:A)),LAMBDA(a,c,LET(d,INDEX(A2:A,c),l,INDEX(B2:B,c),VSTACK(a,IF(d=OFFSET(d,1,),{d,l},{d,l;"",""})))))
```

Or:

```
=LET(_,LAMBDA(o,REDUCE(TOCOL(,1),A2:A,LAMBDA(a,c,{a;IF(c<>OFFSET(c,1,),{OFFSET(c,,o);""},OFFSET(c,,o))}))),{_(0),_(1)})
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's only populating A2:A, instead of B2:B as well. Only the dates are being affected.